# Chart.js Yaxis custom horizontal line and label

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I work with Chart.js and I would like to create a graph like the one in attachment. The idea is to write the values ​​of the Y axis on the horizontal line. Can you help me ??[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `gridLines` and `ticks` styling options to get the intended effect.  [Here is the relevant Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html).

Specifically, for the Y axis, use the following settings:

```
gridLines: {
  drawBorder: false,
  color: '#aaa',
  zeroLineColor: '#aaa',
  tickMarkLength: 10,
  offsetGridLines: true,
},
ticks: {
  padding: 10,
  mirror: true
}
```

The `mirror` and `offsetGridLines` settings are the most important here for creating the appearance of the grid lines extending below the axis labels.

This configuration creates the following effect:
[image: Chart.js stack bar chart with custom grid lines]

Here's a runnable interactive example:

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My First dataset',
      backgroundColor: '#5595eb',
      data: [10, 30, 39, 20, 25, 34, 0],
    }, {
      label: 'My Second dataset',
      backgroundColor: '#433a93',
      data: [18, 33, 22, 19, 11, 39, 30],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
        gridLines: {
          drawBorder: false,
          color: '#aaa',
          zeroLineColor: '#aaa',
          tickMarkLength: 10,
          offsetGridLines: true,
        },
        ticks: {
          padding: 10,
          mirror: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.js"></script>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this plugin can help: [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation)

The plugin annotations like a horizontal line on the specific x/y axis.

Comment: thank you Bemn but after reading the doc i don't think it solves my problem

Comment: Why not?  You can use it to draw horizontal lines and add labels.

Comment: I don't want to draw a line and add a label I want the Y axis label to be written on the horizontal line and not next to it as it is done by default

Comment: Like this : https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/293600/screenshots/3604672/fieldticketanalytics.png